# Outer normal of the set positive definite matrices as a subset of symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Consider the set $S^k$ of $k\times k$ symmetric matrices, and the set $S^k_+$ of $k\times k$ positive definite symmetric matrices. Let the inner product on $S^k$ be entry-wise inner product. Then what is the out normal of $S^k_+$ as a subset of $S^k$. My guess is that the outer normal is negative semi-definite.

Edit: By choosing an orthonormal basis for $S^k$, we can identity $S^k$ with $\mathbb{R}^{k(k+1)/2}$ isometrically. Then, viewing $S^k_+$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k(k+1)/2}$, we can make sense of the outer normal (hopefully almost everywhere when endowed with an appropriate Hausdorff measure on $\partial S^k_+$.

Comment: Could you give us your definition of the "outer normal"?

Comment: The Hadamard product is not an inner product; presumably, you are referring to the Frobenius inner product (the matrix "dot-product").

Comment: The boundary of $S^k_+ \subset S^k$ is not a smooth surface, so it's difficult to understand what exactly the "outer normal" should be, assuming it makes sense to say that $S^k_+$ has one

Comment: Interestingly, the boundary is deceptively smooth looking in the $2 \times 2$ case (which is the only case that can be visualized completely)

Comment: Thanks! All these comments are right, I will edit the question again.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of $S^k_+$ consists of the set of all matrices that are positive semidefinite but fail to be strictly positive definite. Note that this set is not a smooth manifold. Rather, it is a variety with many [singular points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety) at which there is no "normal vector".

As it turns out, the singular points of the boundary are precisely the positive semidefinite matrices that have rank strictly less than $k-1$.

If $A$ is positive semidefinite with rank $k-1$, then the normal vector is defined. In particular, if $x$ is a non-zero vector in the (one-dimensional) kernel of $A$, then $xx^T$ is an inward-facing normal vector on the boundary of $S_+^k$.  So indeed, the outer normal $-xx^T$ is negative semidefinite (more specifically, with rank $1$).

As it turns out, this rank one vector is a multiple of the adjugate $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ of $A$.

---

It's interesting to specifically consider the $2 \times 2$ case.  Relative to the basis
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1},
$$
we find that the set boundary to the set of positive definite matrices is given by
$$
B = \{(a,b,c) : a \geq 0 \text{ and } 2ac - b^2 = 0\}.
$$
We can compute the gradient of $f(a,b,c) = 2ac - b^2$ at any point to find the normal vector
$$
\nabla f = (2c,-2b,2a).
$$
In other words: if the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{a & b/\sqrt{2}\\ b/\sqrt{2} & c}
$$
is positive semidefinite and non-zero, then the normal vector at $a$ will point along the matrix
$$
B = \pmatrix{c & -b/\sqrt{2}\\ -b/\sqrt{2} & a}.
$$
We indeed see that this is a multiple of the adjugate of $A$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide the ref for the first part of your answer?